# Movimento dos fantasmas em pacman

Tags: vb.net

Estou a desenvolver um projeto em vb.net que se trata da minha tentativa de criar o pacman com movimentação de pictureboxes.

Estou próximo de terminar, mas tenho uma grande dificuldade que é definir o movimento dos fantasmas.

Pelo que percebo, ele divide-se em três fases: 1. Movimento aleatório simples, em que se deteta colisões com paredes e define uma nova direção aleatória para se mover; 2. Perseguição ao pacman quando está próximo; 3. Fuga do pacman (quando o pacman consome um "energizer")

Ainda só tenho uma tentativa de código para o movimento 1., com base no que encontrei em pesquisas:

```
Dim movement As ghostmovement
Dim currentLocation As Point
Dim ghostCurrentLocation As Point
Dim random As New Random
 Enum ghostmovement
        up = 1
        down = 2
        left = 3
        right = 4
    End Enum
    Private Sub ghosttimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ghosttimer.Tick
        Select Case movement
            Case ghostmovement.up
                ghost.Top = ghost.Top - 2
            Case ghostmovement.down
                ghost.Top = ghost.Top + 2
            Case ghostmovement.left
                ghost.Left = ghost.Left - 2
            Case ghostmovement.right
                ghost.Left = ghost.Left + 2
        End Select
        DetectCollection(ghost)
    End Sub
    Public Function DetectCollection(ByVal ghost As PictureBox) As Boolean
        For Each wall As PictureBox In WallList
            If ghost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wall.Bounds) Then
                movement = ghostmovement.right
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Mas até esta não funciona, e passo a citar o erro: "Function 'DetectCollision' doesn't return a value on all code paths. Are you missing a 'Return' Statement?"

Se alguém me conseguisse ajudar quanto a este erro e/ou dar alguma sugestão ou explicação dos outros dois tipos de movimento eu agradecia imenso.

Este é o mapa já agora:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Sua função precisa retornar um `Booleano`. O erro diz que que a sua função não está retornando nenhum valor, e realmente não está. Para resolver esse erro você pode fazer assim:

```
Public Function DetectCollection(ByVal ghost As PictureBox) As Boolean
    For Each wall As PictureBox In WallList
        If ghost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wall.Bounds) Then
            movement = ghostmovement.right
            Return True //Bateu na parede, então retorna Verdadeiro
        End If
    Next

    return False //Se chegou até aqui é porque não bateu na parede, então retorna Falso
End Function
```

Porém, acho que não é uma boa você fazer desse jeito. O livro [Clean Code](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/C%C3%B3digo_Limpo.html?id=GXWkDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y), que cita boas práticas na programação, diz que a primeira regra das funções é fazer uma e **somente uma** coisa.
É preferível deixar a função mais genérica, isso é, a função só vai ficar responsável por detectar a colisão, e não mudar a direção do fantasminha:

```
Private Sub ghosttimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ghosttimer.Tick
    Select Case movement
        Case ghostmovement.up
           ghost.Top = ghost.Top - 2
       Case ghostmovement.down
           ghost.Top = ghost.Top + 2
       Case ghostmovement.left
           ghost.Left = ghost.Left - 2
       Case ghostmovement.right
           ghost.Left = ghost.Left + 2
    End Select

    // Está colidindo?
    If IsColliding(ghost) Then
        // Bateu na parede, muda o movimento
        movement = ghostmovement.right
    End If
    DetectCollection(ghost)
End Sub

Public Function IsColliding(ByVal ghost As PictureBox) As Boolean
    For Each wall As PictureBox In WallList
        If ghost.Bounds.IntersectsWith(wall.Bounds) Then
            Return True //Bateu na parede, então retorna Verdadeiro
        End If
    Next

    Return False //Se chegou até aqui é porque não bateu na parede, então retorna Falso
End Function
```

Isso é só uma idéia mas você pode conseguir uma luz a partir desse exemplo

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Não sabia que o que tinha feito era uma má prática, obrigado pelo aviso. Mas a função responsável pela colisão, nomeadamente esta parte:

If IsColliding(ghost) Then
        // Bateu na parede, muda o movimento
        movement = ghostmovement.right
    End If
    DetectCollection(ghost)
End Sub

Isto não seria um problema se colidisse com uma parede colocada à direita? Porque iria tentar mover-se para a direta e continuamente colidir com a mesma

Comment: Sim! Acho que você pode fazer um `While` pra ficar tentando sorteando direções até não bater em nada e aí executar o movimento